# Xamarin.Android. Access to barcode scaner

Tags: xamarin.android

I am writing an Xamarin Android app for Honeywell Scanpal EDA50K and I need access to a barcode scaner.

I tried to use ZXingNet but I don't know how to use it.

Is there any other solution?

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

The device you mention is indeed an Android-based computer, which means it will probably run Xamarin Android apps, but its barcode features appear to be proprietary. The manufacturer provides a dedicated development kit for these scanning features, which is mentioned in [this page](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Where-can-find-EDA50-EDA50k-SDK-for-downloading).

Your best bet is to find out if the manufacturer has a Xamarin scanning SDK that supports your particular device by checking their website or contacting their support.

On the other hand, if you want a general-purpose Xamarin SDK that works on different devices, the company I work for has a library that contains both a [camera control](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/xamarin/camera) and [a barcode decoding engine](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/barcode).